# AWS SageMaker Domain Status "Update_Failed" due to custom image appImageConfigName error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm having some trouble recovering from failures in attaching custom images to my sagemaker domain.

I first created a custom image according to [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-a-custom-image-to-bring-your-own-development-environment-to-rstudio-on-amazon-sagemaker/).

When I use sagemaker console to attach the image built with sm-docker, it appears to successfully "attach" in the domain's image list, but when inspecting the image in the console, it shows an error:

> Value '' at 'appImageConfigName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member
> must satisfy regular expression pattern

This occurs even when the repository or tag are comprised of only alphanumeric characters.

After obtaining this error, I deleted the repositories in ECR.

Since then, the domain fails to update and I am unable to launch any apps or attempt to attach additional images.

The first issue I would like to address is restoring functionality of my sagemaker domain so I can further troubleshoot the issue. I am unable to delete the domain because of this error, even when there are no users, apps, or custom images associated with the domain.

The second issue I would like to address is being able troubleshoot the appImageConfigName error.

Thanks!

[image: image errors]
[image: domain status]

Answer (score 0):

While I was unable to delete the domain via console, I was able to delete it via cli.